# Can $\sum_1^n 1/k$ be arranged so that it is an integer for infinitely many $n?$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, harmonic-numbers

It's well known that when $n>1:$

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\not\in \mathbb{N}$$
But if we are allowed to rearrange the series, we can for instance can get:

$$\frac{1}{1}\in\mathbb{N},\quad\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}\in\mathbb{N},\quad \dots\;?$$

Maybe there is another obvious one that I didn't see.

**Question:** Can the harmonic series be rearranged so that its partial sums hit infinitely many integers?

Answer (score 8):

Answer : YES. It follows from the Erdös-Graham conjecture, which was proved in 2003 by Ernest E. Croot as indicated by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Graham_problem).

I don’t know if there is a more direct proof. [EDIT : there is, as explained in Erick Wong’s comment below].

(If it is not obvious to you how it follows from the Erdös-Graham conjecture, consider a coloring of the integers that uses $n$ different colors, one for each integer between $2$ and $n$, and the last color for all integers $>n$. This shows that (1) there are Egyptian fractions summing to $1$ with arbitrarily large denominators. It follows that (2) For any integer $a>0$, there are Egyptian fractions summing to $a$ with arbitrarily large denominators, and hence that (3) for  any two integers $a,b>0$, there are Egyptian fractions summing to $\frac{a}{b}$ with arbitrarily large denominators).

Comment: There is a more elementary proof of the last sentence.  Just use the fact that every rational $q>0$ admits an Egyptian fraction decomposition (the greedy algorithm works), apply it to $q = N$, and divide through by $N$.

Comment: Also, I think the Wikipedia link points to Erdős-Straus instead of Erdős-Graham :).

Comment: These don't seem to be answering the question as asked.  The problem isn't to just get Egyptian fraction decompositions of 1 with arbitrarily large denominators; the problem is to *partition* the natural numbers into Egyptian fraction decompositions of 1.

Comment: @HarryAltman I’ve added more details to my proof, taking your comment into account.

Comment: I still don't see how this shows the existence of such a partition?  Like, this is talking about individual Egyptian fraction decompositions of 1; you're not checking that they're disjoint from each other, or that every denominator eventually gets used.  (Actually, it's worth noting that, contrary to what I said, technically the question only calls for a partition of the natural numbers into Egyptian fraction decompositions of integers, not necessarily $1$.)

Comment: @HarryAltman Using my (3), just alternate the following two steps : - insert new Egyptian fractions that will make a new integer - insert the smallest unused Egyptian fraction. This way you have a partition of the whole set of integers $>1$, not just a subset. Are you convinced now ?

Comment: Ah, I see -- I think you should be a bit clearer; I took "arbitrarily large denominator" to mean maximum denominator, whereas you meant minimum denominator (thus allowing you to avoid reusing any ones you'd used so far).  You might want to edit this argument in your actual answer.  (Also, by a slight modification of the argument that Erick Wong points out, you don't need any theorems anywhere near as fancy as Croot's; it would probably be best to make this whole answer more elementary.)  But yes, I am convinced now!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Start with $1=1/1$.  Now we've used $1$, so cross that off.  Then since $1$ is crossed off, write $1-1/2=1/2$; $1/2-1/3=1/6$; $1=1/2+1/3+1/6$, and cross off $2$, $3$, and $6$.  Then $1-1/4=3/4$ (since $1$, $2$, and $3$ are crossed off); $3/4-1/5=11/20$; $11/20-1/7=57/140$ (since $6$ is crossed off); etc.

So at each stage, we are trying to decompose $1$ into Egyptian fractions, but with certain fractions (those we've already used) forbidden.  We'll use the greedy algorithm to do this.  We need to show two things: Firstly, that each stage eventually terminates -- that we reach $1$, and move on to the next stage.  Secondly, that every Egyptian fraction gets used at some stage.

For the first of these, let us suppose that at a certain stage we have forbidden set $S$, and that at a certain step of that stage the number remaining left is $r/s$.  (Note that due to the setup, we're only ever dealing with fractions at most $1$, so $r\le s$.)  We're going to subtract off a fraction $1/k$.  Ordinarily, we'd have $k\le \frac{s}{r} + 1$, but since we have a forbidden set $S$, all we know is $k\le \frac{s}{r} + |S| + 1$.  That's still enough to imply that $1/k \ge \frac{r}{s+(|S|+1)r} \ge \frac{r}{(|S|+2)s}$; that is, we're slicing off at least a constant fraction of our fraction at each step, so it will go to zero (even if the process never terminates).

But that means that it will eventually be less than $1/M$, where $M$ is the largest element of $S$; and beyond that point, you are simply applying the greedy algorithm as normal, which we know yields a finite Egyptian fraction expansion.  This proves the first part.

The second part can be proven by strong induction.  Suppose we want to show that $1/n$ eventually gets used; assume that $1/m$ gets used for each $m<n$.  Then at the next stage after these are all used, $1/n$ will be the very first fraction used.

(Note, by the way, that since we're repeatedly decomposing $1$, we will not just hit infinitely many integers, we will hit every positive integer.)

By the way, I computed the first three stages of the process above; the numbers used are as follows:

First stage: 1

Second stage: 2, 3, 6

Third stage: 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 230, 57960

Comment: Your current proof that the greedy algorithm terminates is incorrect because you reason as if the set of forbidden values $S$ stayed the same when you add new values. You forget that the new values cannot be used twice, any more than the old values.

Comment: You're right.  Well -- rather, I didn't forget that; I just intended that $S$ is the set of forbidden values for each stage (i.e. at the beginning of each stage), rather than at each step.  But you're right that my proof is incorrect, because some of the statements I made don't work if it's not the set of forbidden values for each step.  I'll need to see if I can fix this.